# Understanding RAII object

Tags: c++, raii

I'm reading about `RAII` principle and have some questions about it. In fact, it encapsulates the resource. So, consider the class `std::string`. It has a [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) `string (const char* s);`. So, like smart pointers (e.g. [template  explicit shared_ptr (U* p);](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/)) it takes a pointer to the resource and then manages it. Is it correct to say so about `string`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> like smart pointers (e.g. `shared_ptr`) it takes a pointer to the resource and then manages it. Is it correct

Not quite.  `shared_ptr`s take part in ownership of the object to which that pointer points, while `unique_ptr` takes exclusive ownership.  Of smart pointers, `weak_ptr` doesn't take ownership immediately, but it does join as an observer of an object owned by `shared_ptr`s and allows sharing of ownership to be attempted later.

The point is that those smart pointers take ownership of an existing object indicated by the pointer they're given.

`std::string(const char*)`, on the other hand, *makes a copy* of the NUL-terminated string to which the pointer points, which it then has exclusive ownership of.  The original text to which the constructor's pointer argument pointed is of no on-going relevance to the `string` object constructed; for example, modifications to the `string` do not affect that text.  Separately, the `std::string` object may internally keep a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer storing *the copy* of the text, and that buffer can be resized and updated (other times - for sufficiently short text - it may be stored directly in the `std::string` object as an optimisation).  On destruction, `std::string` will `delete[]` any internal pointer it is still managing.  They never leak memory.